# Read each url and save it to seperate pdf Python

Tags: python, list, wkhtmltopdf

I have list of urls and I would want to convert the list of urls to different pdfs for each url . There are about 273 urls in a file

my code is as follows

```
urls= ['https://www.amazon.com/','https://www.google.com/']


import pdfkit
path_wkhtmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)



for i in urls:
    pdfkit.from_url(i, "out.pdf", configuration=config)
```

How can I write it to different pdfs? Thanks in advance.

I want my output to be out1.pdf, out2.pdf..out273.pdf

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: If this is a personal or one of request, you could literally do this with the shell. `i=1; for url in \`cat file_of_urls\`; do wkhtmltopdf $url out$i.pdf; ((i+=1)); done`

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
for i in range(len(urls)):
    pdfkit.from_url(urls[i], f"out{i}.pdf", configuration=config)
```

Comment: my list is as follows

Comment: you want your urls each have their own pdf?

Comment: I have edited my question. The above code only writes pdf of first url

Comment: Yes there are 273 urls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208096/discussion-between-errol-and-anonymous13).